# Minimum numbers of attacks needed

Tags: algorithm

We are given 2 Dimensional grid of cells.Each cell may or may not contain a monster.

We are given a list of cells that contain monsters.

In a single attack we can kill all the monsters standing in a row or in a column. We 
need to tell the minimum number of attacks that will be require to destroy all the monsters.

Constraints:

```
1 ≤ N ≤ 1000

1 ≤ X, Y ≤ 10^9
```

Example:

Input:

```
3

0 0

1 0

0 1
```

Output:

```
2
```

How to approach this problem..??

Comment: @Gray: he tagged it as algorithm. the "what have you tried?" question is still relevant though

Comment: is the grid sparsely populated? Otherwise, its the length of the shortest axis.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I considered that the actual language might not matter, but it can be helpful to definitively know whether it is desired or not. Aren't general algorithms off-topic for SO? Doesn't it need to be a "software algorithm"? I assumed that distinction meant that it required some code.

Comment: Are you required to determine the exact minimum? Or are you expected to find a practically-reasonable solution that does not guarantee the optimal minimum?

Comment: @ AndreyT....We need to find exact minimum..

Comment: Try stabbing them in the hearts!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be modelled as a graph problem.

Create a graph node for each row and column where there's a monster.
Connect the nodes if a monster is on that row and that column.

This is a bipartite graph, and you want to do minimum vertex cover. [König's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_%28graph_theory%29) shows that for bipartite graphs the problem is equivalnt with the maximum matching problem which can be solved in polinomial time:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_matching#Maximum_matchings_in_bipartite_graphs

Answer (score 0):

This reminds me the [Set Cover Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem):

You have a set `U` that stores the `N` monsters: `U = {1, 2, ..., N}`, a set `S` of possible attacks. Each attack is as well a set of the indexes of the monster that the attack kills. In your example, `S` is `S = { {1}, {2}, {}, {1}, {2} }`. You have to find the smallest set `C` in `S` whose union is `U`.

Comment: This answer does not demonstrate this problem is equivalent to the Set Cover Problem. In this problem, not all sets S are possible. E.g., if *a* and *b* but not *c* are in element of S, and *b* and *c* but not *a* are in an element of S, and *b* and *d* are in an element of S, then either *d* is in every element *a* and *b* are in (same “row” as *b* and *a*) or *d* is in every element *b* and *c* are in (same “column” as as *b* and *c*).

Comment: I didn't want to demonstrate this was the Set Cover Problem, but that it can be modelled in a similar way. There are subsets that are not possible in S, but that doesn't stop you from writing S = {{a,b,d},{b,c}} and solve the SCP.

Comment: This problem is not NP-complete.

Comment: That's true, I remove it from my answer.