# Change all Xs in matrix into 0s with the minimum number of steps

Tags: algorithm, multidimensional-array

I have a problem where I have to change all the `X`s in a 2D array into `0`s, and I have to calculate the minimum steps (where a single step consists of changing an entire row or column) required to do so. For example, in an array like-

```
[[X, X, X],
 [X, 0, 0],
 [X, 0, 0]]
```

The minimum number of steps required here is 2.

I thought of a brute force approach (where I am checking row-wise once and column-wise thence and then comparing them to check which takes minimum number of steps) but that would give me an answer of 3, which is not the desired output.

What would be an optimal way to approach this?

Any help, or clue, regarding how I should approach this problem would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Why the [tag:linear-algebra] tag?

Comment: I thought that this could be a Linear Algebra problem since it involves matrices; I'm sorry if I've done something wrong. I'm a newbie, my apologies.

Comment: No problem, not a big deal at all. If that's what you think then you might want to explain a little more about why that's the case in the body of your question. To me, at least, it's not so obvious, so it might help whoever is answering your question.

Comment: I'll go right ahead and edit it.

Comment: Is this from an active programming competition?

Comment: No, my instructor asked the class to do this as a casual exercise.

Comment: Do you have an example that would show that the greedy algorithm fails for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Minimum numbers of attacks needed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19182883/minimum-numbers-of-attacks-needed)

Comment: I'm really sorry, but as I told you, I'm relatively new to programming. Is greedy algorithm a brute force approach? If so, I've already mentioned of my brute-force approach in the question. I'm sorry because of my limited knowledge, please don't down vote me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### HINT 1

Consider the graph that has a vertex for each row and for each column.

Let there be an edge between vertex r_i and c_j if there is an X in the matrix at M[i,j].

### HINT 2

Your problem can be stated as trying to choose a set of vertices (i.e. choosing rows and columns) such that every edge (i.e. every X) touches at least one vertex in the set.

This is called the [minimum vertex cover problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover).

### HINT 3

In general vertex cover is NP-complete, but in this case the graph is bipartite.

### HINT 4

You can solve bipartite minimum vertex cover with a max-flow algorithm to compute the maximum matching between rows and columns. (See [Konig's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_%28graph_theory%29) for more details.)

### SOLUTION

In Python:

```
import networkx as nx

M=[ [1,1,1],
    [1,0,0],
    [1,0,0] ]

G = nx.DiGraph()
for i,row in enumerate(M):
    for j,c in enumerate(row):
        if c:
            G.add_edge('row'+str(i),'col'+str(j), capacity=1.0)

for i in range(len(M)):
    G.add_edge('x','row'+str(i), capacity=1.0)

for j in range(len(M[0])):
    G.add_edge('col'+str(j), 'y', capacity=1.0)

print nx.max_flow(G, 'x', 'y')
```

Comment: I'll need to read up a lot to understand all of that, but thanks for the valuable input!