# Minimum number of lasers required to cover cells in grid?

Tags: algorithm

I was asked this in an interview. I am modifying the question a bit to preserve it from being explicitly Googleable but the gist is:

You are given an `N x M` grid. Some cells in the grid are "evil" (denoted by number 1) and rest are "good" (denoted by 0). You have lasers positioned across each `N` rows and across each `M` columns which when turned on kills all cells in their respective row or column e.g. if you have:

```
   L1 L2 L3 L4
L5  0  1  0  0
L6  0  1  0  1
L7  0  1  1  0
L8  0  0  0  0
```

You can turn on either (L2, L3, L4):

```
   L1 L2 L3 L4
L5  0  x  x  x
L6  0  x  x  x
L7  0  x  x  x
L8  0  x  x  x
```

Or you can turn on (L2, L6, L7):

```
   L1 L2 L3 L4
L5  0  x  0  0
L6  x  x  x  x
L7  x  x  x  x
L8  0  x  0  0
```

A set of lasers turned-on is called "GoodConfig" iff it kills all evil cells. Note you can always turn on all lasers along a row or column and kill everything and it would be "GoodConfig" but turning on lasers is expensive and killing good cells is bad.

1. What is the smallest size of "GoodConfig" i.e. least number of lasers we can turn on till kill all evil cells?
2. What is a "GoodConfig" that minimizes the number of good cells killed?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19182883/minimum-numbers-of-attacks-needed?rq=1) seems essentially the same.

Comment: Looks like this problem when R=C=1 http://community.topcoder.com/stat?c=problem_statement&pm=12447

Comment: @01zhou: I seem to remember the exact same problem as the question at TopCoder with board size up to 18x18 (so that a 2^18 * 18 solution would pass too), but can't find it at the moment.

Comment: I think 18 is too low... The problem seems quite close to the Hungarian algorithm which runs in O(n^3), you can probably easily run it for n = 1000.

Comment: @wrick: Sure, bipartite matching (and bipartite minimum vertex cover) is simple in O(n^3), a bit more technical in O(n^2*sqrt(n)). Please note the "so that a 2^18 * 18 solution would pass too" part of my comment.

Comment: @Gassa: How about part 2 of my question

Answer (score 9):

This problem can be reformulated into the minimum vertex cover problem on a bipartite graph.

Consider a graph: vertices are rows (one part) and columns (the other part). There is an edge between vertices `row` and `col` if and only if the corresponding cell `(row, col)` is evil.

Our problem is now to find a set of vertices having minimal possible size such that each edge (former cell) of our graph has at least one vertex in our set (row or column).

According to [Koenig's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_%28graph_theory%29), we can find the maximum matching in our bipartite graph and then mark exactly one vertex of each edge of the matching so that the resulting set of vertices covers the graph in the above sense. In particular, the size of the maximum matching is equal to the size of the minimum vertex cover.

Answer (score 2):

In order to answer to both 1) and 2), I would go with the following approach, assuming N or M are small (say <= 25).

Brute force on the set of rows/columns (whichever is smaller) selected and check the corresponding cost adding columns/rows to cover everything.

Lets say N <= M, there are 2<sup>N</sup> sets of rows and we process the whole matrix for each one of them. This approach runs in O(2<sup>N</sup> * N * M).

```
#define CONTAINS(mask, bit) (mask & (1 << bit))

void Solve(int matrix[MAX][MAX], int N, int M) {
    vector<int> best;
    int i, j, best_good_cells;
    for (int rows_mask = 0; rows_mask < (1 << N); rows_mask++) {
        vector<int> lasers;
        int good_cells = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            bool add_column = false;
            int good = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
                if (!CONTAINS(rows_mask, i)) {
                    if (matrix[i][j] == 0)
                        good++;
                    else
                        add_column = true;
                }
            if (add_column) {
                lasers.push_back(j);
                good_cells += good;
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
            if (CONTAINS(rows_mask, i))
                lasers.push_back(M+i);
        if (best.size() == 0 ||
                best.size() > lasers.size() ||
                (best.size()==lasers.size() && good_cells < best_good_cells)){
            best = lasers;
            best_good_cells = good_cells;
        }
    }
    cout << "Select lasers:";
    for (auto i: best)
        cout << " " << i+1;
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: I removed the criticism to the other approach. I disagree that the original version didn't answer the question, but I elaborated more on this version.

Comment: Downvoting because the problem has a polynomial time solution and this is too slow.

Comment: i don't see a polynomial solution that minimizes the number of good cells killed. did you ask for any hint?

Comment: Gassa didn't explicitly mention it, but finding a minimum vertex cover of a dense *bipartite* graph has a subcubic algorithm (bipartite is the key here, since the general problem is NP-hard).

Comment: I know the minimum vertex cover part. My point is that it only answers the minimum amount of lasers. If there are multiple configurations with the minimum, the bipartite matching algorithm will pick any of them - it won't minimize the number of good cells killed (question 2).

Comment: fixmeasap has proven that 2) is NP-hard here: http://apps.topcoder.com/forums/?module=Thread&threadID=817858